# Excel: Concatenate last non empty cells in a column

Tags: excel, vba

Since my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589359/excel-last-non-empty-cell-of-a-column) was closed, but the problem remains, I'll rephrase it here. I've came up with the following:

```
Function JoinLastInColIfEmpty(range_ As Range, delim_ As String)
    Dim cell As Range, result As String, current As String

    For Each cell In range_
        current = LastNonEmptyInCol(cell)
        If current <> "" Then
            result = result & current & delim_
        End If
    Next

    If Not IsEmpty(result) Then
        result = Left(result, Len(result) - Len(delim_))
    End If

    JoinLastInColIfEmpty = result
End Function

Function LastNonEmptyInCol(cell_ As Range)
    Dim tmp As Range
    tmp = cell_ '<< The problem occurs here
    Do Until Not IsEmpty(tmp) Or tmp.Row = 1
        tmp = tmp.Offset(-1, 0)
    Loop
    LastNonEmptyInCol = tmp.Value
End Function
```

The problem is that the function never ends, so my questions are:

- What is wrong with my script?
- What should I do to solve [my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589359/excel-last-non-empty-cell-of-a-column)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your direct question, there are a couple of errors in `LastNonEmptyInCol`

```
Function LastNonEmptyInCol(cell_ As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim tmp As Range
    Set tmp = cell_ '<< The problem occurs here  ' <<<<< use Set
    Do Until Not IsEmpty(tmp) Or tmp.Row = 1     ' <<<<< use tmp not cell_
        Set tmp = tmp.Offset(-1, 0)              ' <<<<< use Set 
    Loop
    LastNonEmptyInCol = tmp.Value
End Function
```

That said, I think it is a very inefficient solution, and does not quite solve your stated problem

results will be

```
    A  |  B  |  C  |  D  | Concat
  -----+-----+-----+-----+---------
    1  |  2  |  X  |  5  | 12X5
       |     |  f  |  3  | 12f3
       |  5  |  R  |  12 | 15R12
    Z  |  3  |  T  |     | Z3T12
       |  G  |     |     | ZGT12
```

Here's another version which might be better

```
Function MyJoinLastInColIfEmpty(range_ As Range, delim_ As String)
    Dim vData As Variant
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim result As Variant

    vData = range_

    For i = 1 To UBound(vData, 2)
        If vData(1, i) = "" Then
            Set cl = range_.Cells(1, i).End(xlUp)
            If cl <> "" Then
                vData(1, i) = cl.Value
            End If
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    For i = 1 To UBound(vData, 2)
        result = result & vData(1, i) & delim_
    Next

    MyJoinLastInColIfEmpty = Left(result, Len(result) - Len(delim_))
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, mine was a work in progress and thus no achieving exactly what I expected. Yet, I still have a question: how do I know when to use `Set` (in your example `vData = range_` works without)?

Comment: Use `Set` when you want to assign an object (think of it like assigning a pointer) eg `Set Range1 = Range2` makes `Range1` refer to the same range object as `Range2`.  In `vData = Range_` copies the value of the default property of `range_` into the variable `vData`.  The default property for a range is `.Value` so here `vData` will get the values from the range.  If `range_` referes to >1 cells it will be a variant array

Answer (score 1):

I did not really try to understand the whole thing, but since tmp is an (range) object, you must use
`Set tmp = ....`

Comment: Err, ok... but why? And more importantly how do I know if `Set` is needed?

Comment: All Object variables require "Set" in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

With help rows/columns this can be achieved with formulas:

-Placed in cell `F1` array entered (`Ctrl+Shift+Enter`) then scrolled to however many cells you have:

```
{=INDEX(A$1:A1,MAX(IF(ISBLANK(A$1:A1),0,ROW(A$1:A1))))}
```

-Placed in cell `K1`, refers to first cell in `F1`, no need for array here.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),IF(SUM(NOT(ISBLANK(INDEX($A1:A1,0)))+0)>0,"",F1),F1)
```

-Placed wherever you want the results. `MCONCAT` is a [UDF function found in a free Add-in written in C++](http://xcell05.free.fr/), `CONCATENATE` is Excel's built in formula.

`=MConCat(K1:N1)` or `=CONCATENATE(K1,L1,M1,N1)`

My personal preference would be the VBA way though. I'm sure someone smarter than me could come up with some better formulas.